# Headless execution of watir scripts on windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, headless

I am in a need of running my watir scripts headless. I browsed a lot and found that there is a headless gem for running scripts, but it is specific to linux. I am on windows 7 64-bit so I cannot make use of the headless gem. Is there any way that I can run my watir scripts headless on windows.?

I am using watir 2.0.4 and ruby 1.9.3. And one more thing is that it would be great if their is solution that can work on watir 2.0.4 because I would like to stick to it..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Watir 2.0.4, you would definitely be out of luck. That version of Watir can only drive Internet Explorer. Why do you need headless execution?

Comment: Thanks for the resppnse Justin Ko. Well the application involves popups and it kind of disturbs when working on the system.. So I thought if I could have it run in headless mode.. And also we are planning to integrate it with Jenkins in near future.. Currently We start the scripts manually.. Now that I don't have any luck with this version of watir.. What is the best approach you will suggest.?

Comment: If the only concern is the distribution, you can run your tests in a local VM (virtual machine). I have not used Jenkins, but in theory, you could find a way to use it without actually upgrading Watir versions.

Comment: Yes VM is an option I am aware off.. Since their are other tasks that are carried out on the Jenkins machine I would like to use the same system for running scripts.. So it would be necessary to go headless in the Jenkins system..

Comment: If you need to run it on that Jenkins system as headless, then you will have to upgrade (to Watir-Webdriver specifically, not just Watir-Classic). Alternatively, I would think that the Jenkins system could run a remote task on a Windows system that has your 2.0.4 Watir scripts.

Comment: Thanks Justin.. I will try out but I feel it would be difficult to upgrade to web driver since their is lot of dependency and it would impact on my scripts. Anyways will give it a shot and see how it works out. And what will I have to do on web-driver to run on headless mode..?

Comment: When using Watir-Webdriver, you would want to specify the usage of a headless browser. See the Watir-Webdriver page (http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) for an example.

Comment: Start sipping the linux koolaid. the headless ruby gem uses Xvfb to virtualize a screen. Unfortunately there is no alternative for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have got exactly what you are looking for, check it [here](https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/run-headless-tests-in-windows-linux-unix-using-watir/). I have tried and tested it, its working fine.

It is super is easy to configure and its execution is faster than other GUI browsers.